# How to list all directories in present working directory?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to shell scripting and wanted to list only the directories present in my present working directory.
To do this I found out the following way:-

```
    ls -d */
```

Based on my understanding , this command will search for entities in pwd` that ends with "/" , but there is nothing in my directory that ends with "/", So, how does this expression works?

Also when I do simply do

```
   ls -d
```

why does it simple show a  ". " on the terminal

Comment: owww..from windows (c#, asp and etc) switching to linux.. :) very good

Comment: `/` means a directory.

Comment: @VusP are you saying that "/" is a metacharacter which means directory?

Comment: @ps06756 yes.that what I meant

Comment: @VusP Check [this](http://www.angelfire.com/mi/genastorhotz/reality/computers/linux/bashmetachars.html) out

Comment: @ps06756 ok so metacharacter is not what I thought it is. (really embarassed). What I meant was, We represent directories using a `/`. You can see in the output the directory names will be appended with a `/` . The `/` is assumed internally. Anubhava has worded it in much better technical terms

Comment: @VusP Ok, I understood your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*/` is **shell glob pattern** that only matches directories in the current directory.

You can even get similar output using:

```
echo */
```

`ls -d` just formats it differently.

As per `man ls`:

> `-d      Directories are listed as plain files (not searched recursively).`

Comment: But, I don't have anything in my pwd that ends with /, then how is it matching directories in my pwd

Comment: No your directory names don't have `/` in them but it is the shell's `glob pattern` mechanism that matches all directories when you put a `/` in the end. Read more about globbing: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/06w/notes/glob_patterns.txt

Answer (score 1):

`.` means current directory

try:

```
ls -ld
```

output would show you the detail in current directory

Also we have `pwd` command to show the current working directory...
when you run `ls -d` it is run from the current working directory which is accessible from `pwd` command

At the end of the directory `/` is optional...
but when you are using global path for example `ls /root`... it is necessary to use `/` at first

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command also :

> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.' -exec basename {} ;

'find .' goes through all the files and directories in pwd recursively and '-maxdepth 1' will limit the search to the current directory only and it will not go through the subdirectories, and then the basename(-exec basename {} ) of only directories(- type d) will be displayed except the root directory (! -name '.')